# How do I compute the momentum of a Gaussian wave?

Tags: waves, wavefunction, momentum

I'm very familiar with how the wave-vector is described in the case of plane waves,

$$ f(\vec{r},t) = f_0 \cos\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t \right)$$

Where we see that if we define some phase function $\Phi(\vec{r},t) = \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t $, then we can define the wave-vector, $\vec{\kappa}$ according to,

$$\vec{\kappa} \equiv \nabla \Phi = \vec{k}$$

So the interpretation of $\vec{\kappa}$ becomes the wave-phase spatial gradient (i.e. the rate of change of the wave's phase per unit length).

The momentum of such a wave may then be expressed according to the Einstein-Planck relation,

$$ \vec{p} = \hbar \vec{\kappa} = \hbar \vec{k}$$

Knowing this how do we describe the wave-vector and (more importantly) the momentum for a Gaussian beam?

$$f(\vec{r},t) = f_0 \exp\left(-a|\vec{r}|^2 - b |\vec{r}|\right)\exp\left(i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi(\vec{r})\right)$$

Where we note that the $\phi(\vec{r})$ term holds within it effects relating to both the Gouy phase and wavefront curvature, and define a phase function that houses the wave's dependency on both space and time, $ \Phi(\vec{r},t) = \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi(\vec{r})$.

Is the wave-vector, $\vec{\kappa}$, still taken as being $\vec{\kappa} = \vec{k}$ or is it the spatial gradient of the phase function, $ \Phi(\vec{r},t) = \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t + \phi(\vec{r})$. That is,

$$
\vec{\kappa} = \nabla \Phi(\vec{r},t) \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; \vec{\kappa} = \vec{k}
$$

My question is in specific relation to, if I wanted to compute the momentum of the Gaussian wave, would I consider

$$
\vec{p} = \hbar \nabla \Phi(\vec{r},t) \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; \vec{p} = \hbar \vec{k}
$$

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your plane waves form a basis. So just express your Gaussian in terms of plane waves and the same weights go into your momentum.